# How to transfer files from one ssh to another ssh by scp?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, scp

I want to copy files from one ssh to another ssh using scp command.

```
scp user@host:~/file/to/be/copied user@host:/location/to/save/file/
```

But Following error occurred:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have generated a public key for ssh1 and tried to copy that public to ssh2 again I got error.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried to copy the public key generated on server A to server B in `/.ssh/authorized_keys/`. Then I got

```
WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
```

Help me with this situation.

PS:I'm a university student, and very new to ssh and scp.Please elaborate your explanations, so that I can understand easily.

Comment: did you login to the file source first?

Comment: Is this from one remote system to another remote system?  Or just between your local machine and remote one?

Comment: Steps should be `login to A, then copy from A to B`,  as the keys are already there

Comment: This is from one remote to another. Not from local system to remote system. I have opened those two remote systems on local systems. @Dorian

Comment: Did you try it with the -3 option? `scp -3 source dest`?

Comment: I am getting the same error Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: How did you get the keys on the servers in the first place?

Comment: I have generated the public key by ssh-keygen and stored the keys in the location /.ssh/ folder on remote server A and trying to copy the file to remote server B.